# Valgrind false memory leak for a pointer stored in a static std::list

Tags: c++, valgrind

Valgrind shows a memory leak for a pointer stored in static std::list variable. below is the sample code.

Leak shown for "auto t = new Abc;" ( definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks)

Is this a BUG in Valgrind ?

Is there a solution/workaround (other than clearing the Pool::queue manually) ?

```
 #include <list>

struct Abc
{
    int y = 9;
};

struct Pool
{
    static std::list<Abc*> queue;

    ~Pool()
    {
        for (auto p : queue)
        {
            delete p;
        }       
    }
};

std::list<Abc*> Pool::queue;

int main () 
{
  
  auto t = new Abc; //<<<<<<<<<<< Leak shown for this
  Pool::queue.push_back(t);

  return 0;
}
```

Valgrind output

> g++ -ggdb Main.cpp

> valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out

```
==8807== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8807== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8807== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8807== Command: ./a.out
==8807== 
==8807== 
==8807== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8807==     in use at exit: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==8807==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 72,732 bytes allocated
==8807== 
==8807== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==8807==    at 0x4C2A1E3: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==8807==    by 0x4007D9: main (Main.cpp:26)
==8807== 
==8807== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8807==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==8807==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8807==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8807==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8807==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8807== 
==8807== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8807== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: No object of `Pool` is constructed, then destructor of `Pool` won't be called.

Comment: No, this is not a bug. Your program has a memory leak. Delete the memory.

Comment: i think it is your `for (auto p : queue)`, which creates a *copy* of the queue element which is then deleted. Try `for (auto &p : queue)` instead.

Comment: @U.W. a copy of a pointer is a perfectly correct thing to delete

Comment: @U.W. It's fine because the pointers get copied and the pointees would be deleted at last (if the destructor is called and only once).

Comment: @KamilCuk, there is NO memory leak. "t = new Abc" allocated memory is still reachable at program termination point. So Valgrind should NOT report this as a leak. e.g. if I use a "static Pool::Abc* ptr" and assign the  "t = new Abc" to it. Then no leak is reported.

Comment: @songyuanyao, correct. Question is why Valgrind report this as a leak ?

Comment: If you don't `delete` what you `new` then it's a leak. That the life-time of the object is supposed to be the remaining run-time of the program doesn't really matter.

Comment: The std::list destructs (the compiler takes care of that for a static object), the objects in it don't as that's the job of ~Pool, which you don't call. The Abc instance is not reachable, the leak report is correct.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Valgrind does/should NOT report memory still reachable as a leak. Memory leak is a an allocation which cannot be reached. if it is reachable then it is NOT a leak.

Comment: `Valgrind should NOT report memory still reachable as a leak` Do you have any reference for that? `int *a; int main() { a = new  int; }` is still a memory leak, no?

Comment: @dratenik, you are correct. Pool::queue is destroyed (I can resolve my issue with this). You can post this as the answer. I will accept it.

Comment: @KamilCuk, in your code, since 'a' is a global variable and since it is still reachable at exit, valgrind does NOT report this as a leak. You can verify this

Comment: `valgrind does NOT report this as a leak` Yes I did. And I get: `LEAK SUMMARY: ... still reachable: 4 bytes in 1 blocks`. I see it's counted in `LEAK SUMMARY` section, but not counted in `ERROR SUMMARY` section.

Comment: If "definitely/indirectly lost" is zero then that means no memory leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `std::list` destructs (the compiler takes care of that for a static object), the objects in it don't as that's the job of ~Pool, which the code doesn't invoke anywhere. The `Abc` instance survives and is indeed not reachable, the leak report is correct.

Comment: I stand corrected! And even *with* the explanation it took me a minute to fully understand it. This shows again how important it is to analyze your code with tools like valgrind. They can see problems where you as a person cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @dratenik is the correct answer, I am posting the modified code according to his answer so that some other dev my might find it useful

```
#include <list>

struct Abc
{
        int y = 9;
};


struct List
{
   std::list<Abc*> queue;

   void push_back(Abc* p)
   {
        queue.push_back(p);
   }

    ~List()
    {
           for (auto& p : queue)
          {
              delete p;
          }
     }


};

struct Pool
{
        static List queue;

};

List Pool::queue;

int main ()
{

  auto t = new Abc;
  Pool::queue.push_back(t);

  return 0;
}
```